# Getting rid of spaces in a string

Tags: c#, string, formatting

To add a whitespace seperator in a string we use String.Join().

My question:What(and how) do I have to remove that seperator.

The string's structure is the following "FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF...."

How do I remove the white spaces?

Comment: Are you controlling the code that builds the string? I ask because the easiet way would of course be not to add it in the first place: String.Join("", values)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

C# Has a function for it.

Function is String.Replace(oldstring, newString);

```
String.Replace(" ", "");
```

Comment: A slightly more readable version would be:  String.Replace(" ", string.Empty);  In the end, its the same.

Comment: remember that the string functions leave the original string untouched. So you need i.e. var s = "FF FF FF FF"; var s = s.Replace(" ", ""); (if I remember correctly). Even though I know this, I have forgotten it many times and wondered why my string didn't change, etc. :p

Comment: I find string.Empty to be less readable since quotes are red and string.Empty is not.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you need to use LINQ for this.  Just split on whitespace and then re-join using an empty string as the separator.  This would be best if you had mixed whitespace -- tabs, newlines, etc.

```
var newStr = string.Join( string.Empty, str.Split() );
```

or replace the whitespace with the empty string (this would be the best if all the whitespace where the same character).

```
var newStr = string.Replace( " ", string.Empty );
```